# Difficulty of the Cambridge AS Level

Tags: académique, examens

I'm thinking about taking the *Cambridge AS Level of French Language* in the late 2020, I wonder which level (B1, B2...) would this be on? Is it enough for me to spend 1-2 hours daily to get ready for it from now on?

Link to the specimen papers:
https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/programmes-and-qualifications/cambridge-international-as-and-a-level-french-language-as-level-only-8682/past-papers/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the French language as such, and SE [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be more appropriate.

Comment: According to skills I would say Cambridge AS ranges from CEFR B2 to C1 levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It 's impossible to assess; your present level is what matters most; if you're starting from scratch I'd say one to two hours is not enough; the sample texts are in average French, containing no recherché vocabulary; however the connections to be made between words, as asked by the examiners, are rather difficult; this other task required from the test taker, the rephrasing of whole parts of sentences requires a lot of experience in order to come up with idiomatic equivalents that'll match the original formulation; those are two of the elements I noticed in those tests. It depends also on how fast you learn and on the learning method; there haven't been as yet any magic tricks: learning a language is a difficult task.

You might try this self imposed schedule of yours and see what happens; you'll have the results of a first test so as to go at it again with a better idea of what you need.